# Can't delete from Ubuntu_Free_Culture

Tags: permissions

Some media showed up in my Ubuntu_Free_culture folder which I can't delete. Presumably this has something to do with permissions. I lack root privileges. I'm a complete Linux newbie.

Comment: Where exactly? Can you take a screenshot?

Comment: What file is it? Are you the only user of the computer? Why don't you have root permissions?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you need to be root. If I understood correctly, with "I lack root privileges" you meant that you needed root privileges but you didn't know how to "use these privileges" inside the file manager.

The directory path should be this: `/usr/share/example-content/Ubuntu_Free_Culture_Showcase` so you can delete files using the terminal (command line method) or using your file manager (graphical method).

### Command line

You can do this by running these commands into the terminal: first change your current directory to "Ubuntu_Free_Culture", using:

```
cd /usr/share/example-content/Ubuntu_Free_Culture_Showcase
```

Now you can check the file list with: `ls`.

And remove every file you want to remove by running:

```
sudo rm FILENAME
```

Remember to replace FILENAME with the name of the file you want to remove.

### Graphical

You can just run your file manager (nautilus for Ubuntu, pcmanfm for Lubuntu) with the root privileges, running:

- Ubuntu/GNOME Ubuntu:

  ```
  sudo nautilus /usr/share/example-content/Ubuntu_Free_Culture_Showcase
  ```
- Lubuntu/LXDE:

  ```
  sudo pcmanfm /usr/share/example-content/Ubuntu_Free_Culture_Showcase
  ```

Now you can modify/remove every file.